# Exit a maze with arrows, How to fix the code?

Tags: java, maze

I want to create a code that simulates an exit from a maze with arrows. I think I have a problem with getting out of the maze. The rules are when you can enter the frame of the maze and exit the frame as long as the arrow faces the frame .

This is the code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 6;
    final int NUMBER_OF_ROWS    = 5;

    boolean entryFound  = false;
    boolean exitFound   = false;
    boolean work        = true;
    int     entryIndex  = -1;
    int     exitIndex   = -1;
    int     row         = -1;
    int     column      = -1;

    char[][] pathMatrix = { 
                            { 'O', 'V', 'O', '^', '<', '<' }, 
                            { 'O', 'V', 'V', '*', '^', '^' },
                            { '*', 'V', '*', 'O', '*', '^' },
                            { 'O', 'V', 'O', 'O', 'V', '^' },
                            { 'O', '>', '>', '>', '>', '^' },  };

    for(column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; column++){
        if(pathMatrix[0][column] == 'V'){
            entryFound = true;
            entryIndex = column;
        }
        if(pathMatrix[NUMBER_OF_ROWS -1][column] == 'V'){
            System.out.println(NUMBER_OF_ROWS -1 + " " + column);
            exitFound = true;
            exitIndex = column;
        }

        if(pathMatrix[0][column] == '^'){
            exitFound = true;
            exitIndex = column;
        }

        if(pathMatrix[0][column] == '>'){
            exitFound = true;
            exitIndex = column;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(exitIndex);


    for(row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; row++){
        for(column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; column++){
            System.out.print(pathMatrix[row][column] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print('\n');
    }

    if(entryFound == false || exitFound == false){
        System.out.println("No path has been found in the matrix above");

        return;
    }
    row = 0;
    column = entryIndex;

    do
    {
        System.out.println(row+" "+column);

        if(pathMatrix[row][column] == 'V'){
            row++;
        }

        else if(pathMatrix[row][column] == '>'){
            column++;
        }
        else if(pathMatrix[row][column] == '<'){
            column--;
        }
        else if(pathMatrix[row][column] == '^'){
            row--;
        }
        else {
            work = false;
        }

    }
    while(work == true && (0 < row && row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS) && (0 < column && column < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS));

    if(row == NUMBER_OF_ROWS && column == exitIndex){
        System.out.println("The path has been found in the maze above");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("No path has been found in the maze above");
    }
}
```

and this is the Route : (get out from 0,4 but it doesn't work)

```
O V O ^ < < 
O V V * ^ ^ 
* V * O * ^ 
O V O O V ^ 
O > > > > ^ 
0 1
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
4 2
4 3
4 4
4 5
3 5
2 5
1 5
No path has been found in the maze above
```

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](http://javascriptisnotjava.com)

Comment: Stop using magic strings / chars like `'V'`, define something like `private static final char WHATEVER_THIS_VALUE_MEANS = 'V';` and use that.

Comment: “I think I have a problem ”, you need to describe the issue with your code better than that. May I suggest using the debugger to figure what is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

## The problem

You have 2 errors in your code:

#### 1 - The condition in your loop says

```
while(work == true && (0 < row && row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS) && (0 < column && column < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS));
```

The `0 < row` is wrong, it means that you can't run on the first line which is index 0. But you want to be able to do that, so really you need to write `0 <= row`. So correct it this way:

```
while(work && (0 <= row && row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS) && (0 <= column && column < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS));
```

#### 2 - The condition to verify if you found the exit

```
if(row == NUMBER_OF_ROWS && column == exitIndex)
```

here you check that you exited by the the bottom row, what you want to check is if you exited by the top row, i.e. row is -1. So rewrite it this way:

```
if(row < 0 && column == exitIndex)
```

## Side note

I think you would gain a lot in readability and it would also be lot easier to test if you were split your code into methods. Here is an example:

```
private static final char[][] pathMatrix = {
        { 'O', 'V', 'O', '^', '<', '<' },
        { 'O', 'V', 'V', '*', '^', '^' },
        { '*', 'V', '*', 'O', '*', '^' },
        { 'O', 'V', 'O', 'O', 'V', '^' },
        { 'O', '>', '>', '>', '>', '^' },  };

private static final int NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 6;
private static final int NUMBER_OF_ROWS    = 5;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    printMatrix();

    int[] currentPosition = findEntrance();

    System.out.println("Entrance: " + currentPosition[0] + " " +currentPosition[1] + " " + pathMatrix[currentPosition[0]][currentPosition[1]]);

    while(isInsideMatrix(currentPosition) && isArrow(currentPosition)) {
        System.out.println(currentPosition[0] + " " + currentPosition[1] + " " + pathMatrix[currentPosition[0]][currentPosition[1]]);
        currentPosition = move(currentPosition);
    }

    if(isInsideMatrix(currentPosition)) {
        System.out.println("No path has been found in the maze above");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The path has been found in the maze above");
    }
}
```

Finds the entrance of the maze. Returns the position as an int[] of the form {rowIndex, colIndex}

```
private static int[] findEntrance() {
    char c;

    // scan first and last rows
    for(int column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; column++) {
        // first row
        c = pathMatrix[0][column];
        if(c == 'V') {
            return new int[] {0, column};
        }
        // last row
        c = pathMatrix[NUMBER_OF_ROWS-1][column];
        if(c == '^') {
            return new int[] {NUMBER_OF_ROWS-1, column};
        }
    }

    // scan first and last columns
    for(int row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; row++) {
        // first column
        c = pathMatrix[row][0];
        if(c == '>') {
            return new int[] {row, 0};
        }
        // last row
        c = pathMatrix[row][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS-1];
        if(c == '<') {
            return new int[] {row, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS-1};
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Moves the cursor and returns the next position. Assuming that we are currently standing on an arrow

```
private static int[] move(int[] position) {
    int row = position[0];
    int col = position[1];
    char charAtPosition = pathMatrix[position[0]][position[1]];

    int[] newPosition;
    if(charAtPosition == 'V') {
        newPosition = new int[] {row+1, col};
    } else if(charAtPosition == '^') {
        newPosition = new int[] {row-1, col};
    } else if(charAtPosition == '>') {
        newPosition = new int[] {row, col+1};
    } else if(charAtPosition == '<') {
        newPosition = new int[] {row, col-1};
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Should never come in here.");
    }
    return newPosition;
}
```

Checks if there is an arrow at the given position

```
private static boolean isArrow(int[] position) {
    int row = position[0];
    int col = position[1];
    char charAtPosition = pathMatrix[row][col];
    return charAtPosition == 'V' || charAtPosition == '^' 
        || charAtPosition == '<' || charAtPosition == '>';
}
```

Checks if the given position is inside the matrix

```
private static boolean isInsideMatrix(int[] position) {
    int row = position[0];
    int col = position[1];
    return row >= 0 && row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS
        && col >= 0 && col < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS;
}
```

Prints the matrix

```
private static void printMatrix() {
    for(int row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; row++){
        for(int column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; column++){
            System.out.print(pathMatrix[row][column] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print('\n');
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
O V O ^ < <
O V V * ^ ^
* V * O * ^
O V O O V ^
O > > > > ^
Entrance: 0 1 V
0 1 V
1 1 V
2 1 V
3 1 V
4 1 >
4 2 >
4 3 >
4 4 >
4 5 ^
3 5 ^
2 5 ^
1 5 ^
0 5 <
0 4 <
0 3 ^
The path has been found in the maze above
```

Answer (score 0):

Like somebody else already said, try the debugger or print-statements to test what values you expect your variables to hold at different points in the execution vs. what the actual values are. It appears to me that `row==NUMBER_OF_ROWS` is not what you want to test for in the final if. In your example you need to be at the first row to exit.